# The specified message queue synchronization barrier token has not been posted or has already been removed

Tags: android, handler

**Ahui**
There is no solution to this problem. Who can help solve it?

this is use android handler.

```
2022-10-14 10:36:35.026 4530-4530/com.skkj.app.ditie.gxc I/BlockMonitor: dispatchingThrewException In MainThread
2022-10-14 10:36:35.026 4530-4530/com.skkj.app.ditie.gxc D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
2022-10-14 10:36:35.027 4530-4530/com.skkj.app.ditie.gxc I/QarthLog: [PatchStore] createDisableExceptionQarthFile
2022-10-14 10:36:35.027 4530-4530/com.skkj.app.ditie.gxc I/QarthLog: [PatchStore] create disable file for com.skkj.app.ditie.gxc uid is 10188
2022-10-14 10:36:35.027 4530-4530/com.skkj.app.ditie.gxc E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.skkj.app.ditie.gxc, PID: 4530
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified message queue synchronization  barrier token has not been posted or has already been removed.
        at android.os.MessageQueue.removeSyncBarrier(MessageQueue.java:587)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:2160)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:8887)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1280)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:1019)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:911)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:1248)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:900)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:219)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8668)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:513)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1109)
2022-10-14 10:36:35.042 4530-4530/? I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 4530 SIG: 9
2022-10-14 10:36:42.635 4589-4736/com.skkj.app.ditie.gxc W/Settings: Setting adb_e
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I don't know when the error was reported, but it suddenly appeared.